# How many Conjugacy elements are there?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying the conjugacy class.

I was wondering, how can I count for example how many conjugacy elements of (145)(35)(78) are in A8?

Comment: please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

i think the number of conjugates of the cycle type $(143)(35)(78)$  is $8\choose {3,2,2,1}$ $2!1!1!$  the multinomial coefficient accounting for the selection of $3,2,2,1$ numbers and the remaining part fixes the first element of each cycle.

p.s.(01/26) i made a mistake. need to divide by $2!$ to account for permuting the two 2-cycles. so that the answer is $8\choose {3,2,2,1}$ $\frac{2!1!1!}{2!}$